# First column blocked only when it's not empty

Tags: javascript

I have a grid (with handsontable) but I think that my problem is just a Javascript problem.

In my grid I have some values and I want the first column to be read only just when there is a value in it.

Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hU6Kz/3820/) where I'm trying to do it.

In this example, I want that the cells > A2 A3 A4 < blocked but the > A5 < free.
I just don't find the condition:

```
if (([0].indexOf(col) == 0) && myData[row][0]!='')
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: removing the `!=''` will allow input, but only once.

Comment: It works but that's not what I expected. I can write in the other cells but I don't want that when I add a value, the cell become blocked :/

Comment: Why did you accept an answer to a condition that you don't want?

Comment: @Mouser That's what I asked, now it's my turn to find how to lock the cells only when the grid is loaded. I didn't think that the cells will be blocked just after an edit, and I found it out after your answer.

Comment: It does the same thing as my comment, however you discarded that as not the solution?

Comment: @Mouser But I told you that it worked, and I just precise you that it was not really what I wanted. But I never told you that you comment was wrong to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85406/discussion-between-mouser-and-lison).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it is editable is because you checked for `!= ''`. This check returns `true`, because the value of the column is `undefined`.

If you change your statement to:

```
if (([0].indexOf(col) == 0) && myData[row][0])
```

it checks for a value to exist.

This allows it to be edited only once, and then after a value is edited, it locks the field. This happens because the cells are all evaluated every single time, and after filling in a value, the condition no longer evaluates as `emptycell`

Answer (score 1):

this is what you're looking for:

```
    if(([0].indexOf(col) == 0) && myData[row][0]!=null)
```

---

### edit:

your assumption that an empty cell would be an empty string is wrong ; if you look at the value of row elements [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/hU6Kz/3829/) you'll notice that the initial value is `null`

Comment: it would be more helpful you explain why it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is by using the `row` value: `&& (row >= 1 && row < 4)`

Remember that JavaScript uses zero based indexes. So cell A4 is actually column `0` row `3`.

You select the first column (`0`) and then use the row values to block out the desired cells.

http://jsfiddle.net/hU6Kz/3822/

In this solution I took it a bit further:

http://jsfiddle.net/hU6Kz/3826/

By using an object(global var in this case) you can set the cell you want disabled. Since the cells function iterates over every cell.

```
var disabledCells = {0 : {1 : true, 2 : true, 3 : true}, 1 : {3:true}};
```

This is the object. the properties refer to the column and cell. When 0,1 is true it will disable `A0`.

This function comes with it:

```
function returnReadOnlyCells(row, col)
{
    if(disabledCells[col] && disabledCells[col][row] ) //Here I'm trying to block the cells I want
    {
        return {readOnly : true};
    }
    else
    {
        return {};
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I want a dynamic function. Here, this is just for specifics row, in my application, the number of row to block is never the same :/

Comment: This is the lead to the answer. If you can block it hardcoded, you can block it dynamically. Also your question isn't clear on that.

Answer (score 0):

**USE:**

```
if(([0].indexOf(col) == 0) && (row >= 1 && row < myData.length -1) )
```

Restrict it by checking the myData array's length. So you can edit all the **row > array's length.**

Comment: Add some explanation to your code, explain what principle to use in order to solve the problem but avoid answering with just a code snippet by any possible way.